# Datatables Editor: Using the PHP data() method to access data before it is output

Tags: php, jquery-datatables-editor

According to the [documentation here](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/getting-started#Return-data) you can access the data before json_encoding it. There is no further mention of *how* to access the data. What array is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Datatables Forum answer](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/105720#Comment_105720)

> Its an array in the same format as the JSON returned to the client. So for example you can get the data array using $editorData['data']; and then do whatever you need with that array (presumably looping over it and changing its contents).
>
> Allan